# How do I pass a new value to the Redux store via onPress?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm a Vue dev trying to get to grips with React Native & Redux - I'm well versed in Vuex but I am struggling to understand the Redux structure.

As far as I can see with console logs, I have set up the actions/store properly.

I'm trying to get a button to set the state in the store with an onPress. This is the button:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      address: state.address
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {  
  return {
      address: (value) => dispatch({ 
        type: 'UPDATE_ADDRESS',
        placeName: value })
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

And my button/text to change the information and show the information

```
      <Button
        title="set address"
        onPress={() => this.props.address('new address')}
      />
      <Text>{store.getState().placeName}</Text>
```

The reducer file looks like this:

```
const addressReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log("in here");

  switch(action.type) {
    case UPDATE_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        placeName: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

But when I console.log out `action.payload`, it's undefined.

Can you not pass values to the store like this? When I click the button, `<Text>{store.getState().placeName}</Text>` doesn't update, it just says "Hello world" still.

Comment: Try updating your reducer like so:

`placeName: action.placeName`

Comment: Hey, it looks like that has worked in the console log thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: @DacreDenny am I using the store getter correctly to render the state? I think that the state value is updating, but visually the text says "hello world" when I click the button rather than 'new address'

Comment: One moment - I'll answer to try and clarify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is almost correct - just a few tweaks to get it over the line.

First, your `UPDATE_ADDRESS` action is passing the "value" to the reducer via `placeName` rather than `payload`. In your reducer, make the following change to ensure that you're accessing `placeName` (rather than `payload` which will be undefined):

```
case UPDATE_ADDRESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        /* placeName was defined in your action creator */
        placeName: action.placeName 
      };
```

Lastly, to ensure the UI renders when store changes occur (ie after your reducer processes the `UPDATE_ADDRESS` action) you'll want to update your `render()` method like so:

```
  <Button
    title="set address"
    onPress={() => this.props.address('new address')}
  />
  { /* Render placeName via prop provided by mapStateToProps */ }
  <Text>{ this.props.placeName }</Text>
```

The `placeName` prop is defined/provided by your `mapStateToProps()` function, when your `<Home />` component is "connected" to the store.

The way to look at `mapStateToProps()` is that it map bits of state that your `<Home />` component is interested in (ie from your global store), to actual props that are passed to the `<Home />` component.

That's why you can then access `placeName` via `this.props` from within your `<Home />` components render method -

hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time with this. Having made these changes, the text has stopped rendering. You can see the code here to if I'm missing something obvious: https://github.com/ShetlandJ/ShetlandCC

Comment: You're welcome - what does the initial state of your store look like?

Comment: That's the reducer file

Comment: Wait, I got it!

Comment: ah ok, you're using `combineReducers()` which adds a bit more structure to your store - I'll update the answer

Comment: oh, nice! you did `store.places.placeName` ?

Comment: I wasn't setting the correct bit in mapStateToProps :)

Comment: Cool! glad I could help - please consider accepting the answer if it has been useful :-)